# Does SQL server share data pages?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, data-pages

I am trying to understand more about how data is allocated to the 8KB data page:

1. Can the same page be shared with rows from other databases?
2. Can the same page be shared with rows from other tables?

Answer (score 2):

1: No

2: No

A page is owned by an allocation unit:

1. You have the actual data in the table, which can be as a heap or a clustered index.
2. You have x number of non-clustered indexes.
3. Both 1 and 2 above can have LOB columns with off-row data (varbinary(max), for
   instance).
4. Both 1 and 2 above can of row overflow data, where for instance 2 varchar(8000) columns fully populated won't fit on a page meaning one or more columns are stored off-row. Similar to 3 above, but for a limited variable length data type instead of max types.
5. All above (the ones that you have) has their own allocation units. They do not share pages.
6. Furthermore, 1 and 2 above can be partitioned, in that case you would multiply 1-4 above with home many partitions you have - giving you your allocation units. again, data isn't page-shared across allocation units.

Answer (score 1):

1 - No

2 - No

The Microsoft documentation on pages and extents is very comprehensive
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15